How to toggle print output between a Text widget and the console (Python 3.11)
I want to send print ouput either to a Text window or to the console, at will. My code works correctly if I start sending to the console, but once I have ouput to the Text window, impossible to ouput back to the console.
Here is my code:
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import scrolledtext  
import sys  

def redir(text):  
    Twidg.insert(INSERT,text); Twidg.yview(END)  

def aff_widg():  
    Twidg.configure(state = "normal")  
    sys.stdout.write = redir  
    print("Contenu de la BD:\n")  
    Twidg.configure(state = "disabled")  

def aff_cons():  
#    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    sys.stdout = original
    print("Contenu de la BD:\n")  

fen = Tk()  
fenpr = Toplevel(fen)  
fenpr.geometry("200x100+250+20")  
original = sys.stdout  
Twidg = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(fenpr, wrap = WORD,\  
                                   height = 20, width = 100)  
Twidg.place(x=10,y=10)  
Button(fen, text = "To Textwidg", command = aff_widg).pack()  
Button(fen, text = "To console",  command = aff_cons).pack()  
fen.mainloop()

